# Atribuir Json muito grande em uma variável em forma de String

Tags: javascript, json

Quero fazer uns testes em um algoritmo que estou desenvolvendo [com este Json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JvmgK4skVwS7xkCqhwCHvzy5gKgrGYAg/view?usp=sharing).

Para testar esse tipo de entrada, eu sempre criava uma variável atribuindo o json entre crases, desta forma a variável ficava com o conteúdo de string em várias linhas e depois usava o `Json.parse()` para converter a string em um objeto Json, porém, este Json aí em específico, não consigo atribuir ele em forma de string usando a crase, acredito que por ele ser muito grande. O que posso fazer nessa situação?

Comment: Podes colocar o código que estás a usar para isso sff, para transformar o json em objeto

Comment: basicamente é isso: `var dados= \`conteudo do json\`; var arquivoJson = JSON.Parse(dados); `

Comment: Parece estar tudo bem: https://jsfiddle.net/c3a9pa5j/ , dá uma olhada na consola

Comment: Por ai deu, eu estou testando em um arquivo .html em meu computador, neste arquivo eu coloco uma tag `<script>` e faço meus testes de javascript, porém com esse json ai não funciona.